# Angular 2 - Reset value of INPUT element type FILE

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In an angular2 app I have an innocent html INPUT element (type FILE) which I use to select a file. Here is the guy

```
<input #selectedImage id="selectImage" type="file" name="image" (change)="imageSelected($event)">
```

I need to be able to RESET the selection once the user clicks the 'reset' button.
I can do this easily if I use @ViewChild decorator and manipulate the input element via code, i.e.

```
@ViewChild('selectedImage') selectedImageFile;

reset() {
    this.selectedImageFile.nativeElement.value = '';
}
```

Now I would like to do the same via property binding and here I find obstacles. I change the code as follows

```
<input id="selectImage" type="file" name="image" value={{selectedImageFile}} (change)="imageSelected($event)">

reset() {
        this.selectedImageFile = '';
}
```

but now nothing works (i.e. the selection of the INPUT element gets not cleared when I click the reset button). I am sure I am missing something pretty trivial but, as sometimes happens, my eyes are blind now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `[value]="selectedImageFile"` inside your input tag?

Comment: Yes. Same result. Thx anyway

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this ? I am needing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't work initially but it wouldn't work for successive calls anyway because you would need to set `selectedImageFile` to a value `!= ''` for Angular to recognize the change.

After the first `reset()` it would be `''` and each successive call would be ignored because there is no change.

Setting it to a value `!= ''` would throw error because `<input type="file">` doesn't allow to set a different value than `''` programmatically.